# js class static method refer to self (like self in php)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to refer to the class that a static method is included in without explicitly specifiying the class again. So instead of this:

```
class User {
    static welcome = 'Hello'

    static greet() {
        console.log(User.welcome)
    }
}
```

Something like this:

```
class User {
    static welcome = 'Hello'

    static greet() {
        console.log(self.welcome)
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no class instance with a static method, so there's no `self` to refer to.

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. What do you want to achieve from this?

Answer (score 6):

A class is nothing but a function object. Static methods are nothing but function properties on that object. Whenever you call `obj.method()`, `this` refers to the object inside that function.

So if you call the method with `User.greet()`, `this` will refer to the function object `User`.

```js
class User {
  static get welcome() {
    return 'hello';
  }

  static greet() {
    console.log(this.welcome)
  }
}

User.greet();
```

---

Inside *instance methods* you can refer to the class via `this.constructor`.

Answer (score 3):

You can allways use "this":

```
class User {
  static welcome = 'Hello';

  static greet() {
        alert(this.welcome)
  }
}

User.greet();
```

But in case of static methods it will refer to type itself.

Here is what [specs says](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.8.11) about value of "this":

> When the root declaration is an instance member or constructor of a
>   class, the ThisType references the this-type of that class.
>
> When the root declaration is a member of an interface type, the
>   ThisType references the this-type of that interface.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no such thing as `self` in JS, since `this` in JS is basically already a "merge" of `this` and `self` as described in other answers.

If you don't like to do `this` for a static call, you can actually do pretty similar thing as in PHP.

**TL;DR Refer to the class by its name e.g. `MyClass.myMethod()`**

```
class A {
    static one () { console.log("I am one"); }
    static two () { A.one(); }
}
A.one(); // Outputs/Logs: "I am one"
```

PHP equivalent could be something like

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function one() { echo "I am one"; }
    public static function two() { A::one(); }
}

A::two(); // Outputs: "I am one"
```

Bonus info: In JS, you can even do `static two = () => A.one();`, which is not available with arrow functions in PHP since in class `static` variable implies constant expression.